# GUI for a MQTT server on NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I have a MQTT bridge and I needed a GUI for it to show status of connectivity and metrics such as how many locally connected devices, messages received from local devices.

Both the MQTT bridge and the GUI will be on the same raspberry pi.

Looking through the options, but it seems that making the GUI as a web, running in Express, and connects to the MQTT bridge (mosca) via websocket over localhost, is the only option?

Is there other UI framework in NodeJS that supports model bindings without having to do an connection with the localhost? Trying to reduce the number of connections to the MQTT bridge which is a Mosca server on NodeJS.

Putting in another way: I noticed Desktop Apps using ExpressJS does not support modal bindings, and if there is any change of values such as new clients connected to the server, I need to reload the whole page? I can achieve modal bindings with a web page with say AngularJS, but it also means the web app is isolated from the MQTT server running NodeJS. I am just wondering if there is any framework that I can merge web JS and backend NodeJS into single app.

Comment: I think this question is to broad to get a proper answer as it stands

Comment: Thanks for your comment @hardillb. In summary, I am looking the correct way of doing a GUI on the same machine as the server.

While web app is the easiest, I am wondering where should I keep the state of the metrics: in the webapp or in the server?

That's why I wonder, what other alternatives I have beside writing a web app? Does NodeJS has a way to wring a native UI app? Does Electron allows me to fire an event from within the Electron stack to the UI with some backend changes?